# List Template Information

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

If I create a custom list and create several workflows and custom NEW and EDIT forms are these included when I template the list?

Answer (score 1):

List forms and views will be included in the template.

Workflow is an item that you can't move with templates.  All the STP templates do is to make a copy of your list in the content database and makes it available to other sites that share the same definition as the one in which it was created.  If you want to add a workflow to this list, you'll have to recreate it in the destination.

Another option is to export the list and import it in destination.

Comment: So if I export th elist and then import it to the new destination site will it contain all of the Forms and Workflows? Thanks